# Align text to right-hand edge of centered image?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I am including an image in a beamer presentation, centred, and want to give an unintrusive attribution link, just under the picture, right-aligned to the right-hand edge of the image.

In other words, I’d like something almost like what’s produced by

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
     \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{file_extensions.png} \\
     \url{http://xkcd.com/1301}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

except with the url shifted horizontally, so that its right-hand edge is flush to the right-hand edge of the image.  How can I achieve this?

[(Image file for MWE.)](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/file_extensions.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or use a `minipage`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} \\
\raggedleft\url{http://xkcd.com/1301}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use a `tabular`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image} \\
\url{http://xkcd.com/1301}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

...or use a right-aligned stack

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
     \def\stackalignment{r}\stackunder[6pt]{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}%
     }{%
      \url{http://xkcd.com/1301}%
     }
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Or use a `makebox`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image}\\ 
\makebox[0.6\textwidth][r]{\url{http://xkcd.com/1301}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Or `\llap` and `\raisebox`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}% no space here !
\llap{\raisebox{-10pt}{\url{http://xkcd.com/1301}}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Or even a `\vbox`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hspace{-.2\textwidth}
\vbox{
\raggedleft
\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image}\\
\url{http://xkcd.com/1301}}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```